# How to count who has most hits in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a table with a column called **bid** and I would like to list how many records there exists with each **bid** value.

Kind of making a TOP TEN list.

Example:

**bid** with value 1 has 5 entries/rows.
**bid** with value 2 has 3 entries/rows.
**bid** with value 3 has 8 entries/rows.
etc

How do I make a query that counts and sums up each of the **bid's** and sort the in a DESCending order?

Thankful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work in MySQL

```
select u.firstname, t.bid, count(*) as counts
from your_table t
join users u on u.bid = t.bid
where t.confirmed <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
group by t.bid
order by counts desc
```

Generally you can do

```
select u.firstname, t.bid, t.counts
from 
(
  select bid, count(*) as counts
  from your_table 
  where confirmed <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  group by bid
) t
join users u on u.bid = t.bid
order by t.counts desc
```

Comment: Awesome! That was just to the point! I'd like to extend this one step further. If a have a secondary table where **bid** also exists, but it has a column **firstname** as well. Would it be possible to have that displayed too?

Comment: The first you wrote (above the _Generally you can do_) kind of solved it. Had to do a minor change. Instead of **f.firstname**, I put **u.firstname**. I was even able to add **u.lastname** and get it merged.

Comment: If I have to put in a WHERE NOT in the syntax, where should that be in the above example? I have a columned called **confirmed** and it must not contain **0000-00-00 00:00:00**. If it does, it should be excluded.

Comment: My hats off for you Sire. You totally rock the world of MySQL! :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT bid, count(*) as TotalHits
FROM tableName
GROUP BY bid
```

if you want result as per hits sorted, use

```
SELECT bid, count(*) as TotalHits
FROM tableName
GROUP BY bid
ORDER BY TotalHits DESC
```